# ArticleException: You must `download()` an article first

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, nlp

I have a data frame of article urls (df) that I want to scrape using the news-please crawler

```
from newsplease import NewsPlease

result = []
for i in df["web_url"]:
  result.append(NewsPlease.from_url(i).maintext)
# note that result is a list of the articles. 

# we have to convert the list of articles content, in a text file, so that we can tokenize that text file into sentences.
textfile = open("nyarticles.txt", "w") 
for element in result:
    textfile.write(element + "\n")
textfile.close()
```

This code should scrape the article text for every url and then combine it into a single text file, but instead I get this error message:

```
not a 200 response: 410
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ArticleException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-c013b6e9715b> in <module>()
      3 result = []
      4 for i in df["web_url"]:
----> 5   result.append(NewsPlease.from_url(i).maintext)
      6 # note that result is a list of the articles.
      7 

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/newspaper/article.py in throw_if_not_downloaded_verbose(self)
    527         """
    528         if self.download_state == ArticleDownloadState.NOT_STARTED:
--> 529             raise ArticleException('You must `download()` an article first!')
    530         elif self.download_state == ArticleDownloadState.FAILED_RESPONSE:
    531             raise ArticleException('Article `download()` failed with %s on URL %s' %

ArticleException: You must `download()` an article first!
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The error says exactly what's wrong: you must call `download()` method first before you can access the `.maintext` property:

```py
from newsplease import NewsPlease

result = []
for i in df["web_url"]:
  article = NewsPlease.from_url(i)
  article.download()
  result.append(article.maintext)
```